# jQuery click/change even on select is not working

Tags: jquery, click, onchange

I'm trying to capture the change of the drop list, however the click and change event didn't work no matter in ff or chrome. Here's the source html code:

```
<select class="select" id="querycond_select_Baitgenesymbol" style="max-width: 400px">
    <option>APC</option>
    <option>CTNNB1</option>
    <option>DNMT1</option>
    <option>ELF3</option>
    <option>EPHB2</option>
    <option>MRE11</option>
```

and jQuery:

```
$('.select').click(function() {
    alert("!!!!!!!")
});
```

I also tried to replace the click with change, but it didn't work out for me too.

Comment: Did you place the above js fn in jQuery dom ready event handler?

Comment: Did you use a closing `</select>` tag? Did you use a `$(document).ready` wrapper? http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/rfZwz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

works just fine ... http://jsfiddle.net/tXy6Q/  try adding it in document.ready()

- if the select box is added dynamically based on logic would recommend using [live](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=jquery%20api%20live&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Flive%2F&ei=VRe6Tob_FIXsrAfgytWkBg&usg=AFQjCNHPnKvzKaTw54m1H-YHMmd8NEWjTQ)()
  method..
- use the change event rather than click
- also check for any errors using firefox error console ..

Comment: I've added it in document.ready() and used bind() and change event, however it's still not working. The select box is indeed added dynamically, there's very few example on the internet, could you please show me an example? thanks!

Comment: if it is dynamic this should do the trick $('.select').live('click change', function() { alert("!!!!!!!"); }); on a side note just noticed that you missed ; afer the alert message....anyhow do check and let us know ..... cheers!!

Comment: I used bind and place the function inside the logic where the select box is added dynamically, then it's working! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to:

- include jQuery on your page
- Wrap your code in `ready` handler
- use `change` instead of `click`

---

```
$(function(){
  $('#querycond_select_Baitgenesymbol').change(function() {
    alert("!!!!!!!");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#querycond_select_Baitgenesymbol").change(function(e){
        alert("here");
    });
});
```